# Typescript, Browserify and angularjs beyond the two file example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, browserify, commonjs

I am trying to move a very large angularjs project written in typescript from AMD to CommonJS.
I have found several examples online, but cannot find an example that would cover a real project combining the three.

**Short version:**
If I remove the TS modules then I cannot find a way to use interfaces in other files unless declaring one per file.
If I keep TS modules then it becomes cumbersome to use exported items since I need to declare the require and then go down the whole TS module namespace even within the module itself.

**Long version:**
Up to this point I have been using the typescript module system so far and I am happy the way it worked. From what I understand it is not necessary to use the ts module system when using browserify since you are requiring specific parts of the app before using them and it would not be as transparent to use something that polluted the global scope (did I get this correct?). If I remove everything from inside the typescript modules and have code in snake-page-controller.ts like:

```
'use strict';

interface ISnakePageController {
    isLoggedInUser: boolean;
}

class SnakePageController implements ISnakePageController {
    public isLoggedInUser:boolean = false;

    static className:string = 'SnakePageController';
    static $inject:string[] = [];

    constructor() {
        console.log('snake controller created.');
    }
}

export = SnakePageController;
```

then i can use this controller from an index.ts file like:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
'use strict';

import angular = require('angular');
import directives = require('./directives');
import snakeController = require('./snake-page-controller');

var snakeModule:ng.IModule = angular.module('mike.snake', [
    directives.name
])
.controller(snakeController.className, snakeController);

export = snakeModule;
```

Then everything works BUT,

1. I can no longer put the export keyword in front of the interface since then the compiler complains about multiple exports per file. So how can I use this interface outside the file it was declared in? Do I have to create separate files for each interface and require that (this would seem awkward)?
2. If index.ts was written in JS the I would be able to write:

   angular.module('mike.snake', [
         require('./directives').name
   ]

inline. But if I write this in TS the compiler complains with TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'. This might seem just an annoyance, but I would love to be able to type the required modules inline and not have to import them and use them in two different places.

Having the above difficulties and not being crazy about having to remove the TS module code from 10s of files I tried sticking with the typescript module system and making it play nice with the browserify module system, but...

Having snake-page-controller written like:

```
'use strict';
export module Mike.Snake {
    export interface ISnakePageController {
        isLoggedInUser: boolean;
    }

    export class SnakePageController implements ISnakePageController {
        public isLoggedInUser:boolean = false;

        static className:string = 'SnakePageController';
        static $inject:string[] = [];

        constructor() {
            console.log('snake controller created.');
        }
    }
}
```

I get access to both the class and the interface outside the file, but I have to drill down the whole module namespace even within the same module: ie.

```
//part of index.ts which is in the same TS module with SnakePageController
.controller(snakeController.Mike.Snake.SnakePageController.className, snakeController.Mike.Snake.SnakePageController);
```

Is there a full blown typescript,angularjs and browserify example out there and I missed it?

Comment: Your question got me pretty curious, and I think that how you're doing it might be mostly correct; but you should be able to import the long namespace names in your example into a simpler local name at the top of files that use them. Found this link: http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/javascript-namespacing-with-typescript-internal-modules/ But I'm unable to verify since I don't have a Typescript project set up to try it in.

Comment: I managed to get both interfaces in the same file and not walking down whole namespace, by removing the namespacing but keeping exports. Not sure if this is correct though https://gist.github.com/masimakopoulos/d2e28b638b664d305c94

Comment: I just had another read through the TS docs about modules https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Modules and it seems that removing namespacing and exporting the interface and the class is the proper way.

Comment: The example I was thinking of (and maybe it didn't work) was something like: `var SnakeController = import Mike.Snake.SnakePageController`, or `import SnakeController from "Mike/Snake"`. I feel like namespaces are a good idea and shouldn't be discarded.

Comment: @Katana314 check out the link I posted on my previous comment linking to typescript documentation, where they explain why removing the namespace is not a bad thing when using external modules titled "Needless Namespacing"

Comment: I have been unable to find an example for this either as I wanted to use browserify/tsify to concatenate all my JS together.  When I import angular though and try to declare an angular module it tells me angular doesn't exist unless I have a separate script tag for Angular in the HTML, so clearly it isn't including angularjs in my app.js file with the compiled typescript.

Answer (score 0):

> I can no longer put the export keyword in front of the interface since then the compiler complains about multiple exports per file

Tip: don't use `export =`. Only use named exports and then you can export more than one thing

> So how can I use this interface outside the file it was declared in?

Recommend you put interfaces in a `globals.d.ts` file. More : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: Can you please give an example of named exports? Also having all the interfaces in a single place goes against the modularity I have currently achieved in my project where every module is self contained. Also I will face name clashes where two modules might have the same interface names

Comment: Also, how come I cannot use require in-line without using import and storing it first? I see you use import/from syntax, isn't this ES6 or does it work with typescript as well (I tried and get an error from webstorm)? BTW I have tried export declarations similar to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242 but tsc doesn't seem to like them compiling using --target ES5 -module "commonjs"

Comment: Reason for downvote: I think the complication of his import (which then leads to his choice of export method) is how to actually *bring the file in*. Referencing a d.ts file in a comment helps the IDE, but doesn't actually write an AMD/Common/etc import for the file.

Comment: `Referencing a d.ts file in a comment helps the IDE, but doesn't actually write an AMD/Common/etc import for the file` A `.d.ts` file *does not generate any .js* Therefore importing it for AMD/Common/etc is meaningless